# <neon-animated-pages> does not work with <paper-tabs>?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

## Question

> **It is not possible to use `<paper-tabs>` inside a custom element to `[[select]]` `<neon-animated-pages>` right now. Correct?**

The comment by [@FelixEdlemann](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCIWecRnGzCxGvmeofpw7HgQ):

> But I still didn't find a solution for using neon-animated-pages in combination with paper-tabs.

on [this Youtube video by @RobDodson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wMhq1o0DULM&index=1&list=PLmccrGoe3AUDPa-DeKlVimmrkU5gUlImC) seems to support my experience that using `<paper-tabs>` (inside a custom element) breaks `<neon-animated-pages>` right now.

---

#### Please provide working example.

**If I'm wrong. And if it is possible to use `<paper-tabs>` to `[[select]]` `<neon-animated-pages>`, could somebody please post a working example?**

---

My proof of this theory is that simply changing only the `<iron-pages>` element to `<neon-animated-pages>` causes the following code to go from "working" to "not working."

What happens is, when trying to use `<neon-animated-pages>`, all the pages appear on `<my-view>` at the same time. As it would if there were no `<neon-animated-pages>` element tag at all.

### Working Code

index.html

```
<my-view>...</my-view>
```

my-view.html

```
<template>
  <iron-pages class="flex" selected="[[selected]]">
  <!--Changing only the above line to <neon-animated-pages breaks it-->
    <my-page-1></my-page-1>
    <my-page-2></my-page-2>
    <my-page-3></my-page-3>
  </iron-pages>
  <paper-tabs selected="{{selected}}">
    <paper-tab><iron-icon icon="home"></iron-icon></paper-tab>
    <paper-tab><iron-icon icon="star"></iron-icon></paper-tab>
    <paper-tab><iron-icon icon="perm-media"></iron-icon></paper-tab>
  </paper-tabs>
</template>
```

### Not Working Code

index.html

```
<my-view>...</my-view>
```

my-view.html

```
<template>
<!-- The below tag is what seems to break it / stop it from working --> 
  <neon-animated-pages
      class="flex"
      selected="[[selected]]"
      entry-animation="slide-from-left-animation"
      exit-animation="fade-out-animation"
  >
    <my-page-1></my-page-1>
    <my-page-2></my-page-2>
    <my-page-3></my-page-3>
  </neon-animated-pages
  <paper-tabs selected="{{selected}}">
    <paper-tab><iron-icon icon="home"></iron-icon></paper-tab>
    <paper-tab><iron-icon icon="star"></iron-icon></paper-tab>
    <paper-tab><iron-icon icon="perm-media"></iron-icon></paper-tab>
  </paper-tabs>
</template>
```

Working JsBins per @zerodevx:

- [At top level index.html](http://jsbin.com/vudinaziwe/edit?html,output) | http://jsbin.com/vudinaziwe/edit?html,output
- [Inside custom element](http://jsbin.com/bejahumeru/edit?html,output) | http://jsbin.com/bejahumeru/edit?html,output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see why not - unless `<neon-animation>`'s API has changed, your page elements need to implement `Polymer.NeonAnimatableBehavior`. The `<neon-animatable>` element is a convenience element for that. You also need to import the specific animations you are using.

In your example, your imports should should look something like:

```
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animated-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animatable.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/neon-animation/animations/slide-from-left-animation.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/neon-animation/animations/fade-out-animation.html">
```

While your body might look something like:

```
  <template is="dom-bind">
    <paper-tabs selected="{{selected}}">
      <paper-tab>PAGE 1</paper-tab>
      <paper-tab>PAGE 2</paper-tab>
      <paper-tab>PAGE 3</paper-tab>
    </paper-tabs>
    <neon-animated-pages class="flex" selected="[[selected]]" entry-animation="slide-from-left-animation" exit-animation="fade-out-animation">
      <neon-animatable>PAGE 1 CONTENTS</neon-animatable>
      <neon-animatable>PAGE 2 CONTENTS</neon-animatable>
      <neon-animatable>PAGE 3 CONTENTS</neon-animatable>
    </neon-animated-pages>
  </template>
```

Working jsbin: http://jsbin.com/vudinaziwe/edit?html,output

**UPDATE 1:**

Applying this inside a custom element,

x-test.html

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">    
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animated-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animatable.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/neon-animation/animations/slide-from-left-animation.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/neon-animation/animations/fade-out-animation.html">    
<dom-module id="x-test">
  <template>
    <paper-tabs selected="{{selected}}">
      <paper-tab>PAGE 1</paper-tab>
      <paper-tab>PAGE 2</paper-tab>
      <paper-tab>PAGE 3</paper-tab>
    </paper-tabs>
    <neon-animated-pages class="flex" selected="[[selected]]" entry-animation="slide-from-left-animation" exit-animation="fade-out-animation">
      <neon-animatable>PAGE 1 CONTENTS</neon-animatable>
      <neon-animatable>PAGE 2 CONTENTS</neon-animatable>
      <neon-animatable>PAGE 3 CONTENTS</neon-animatable>
    </neon-animated-pages>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "x-test",
      properties: {
        selected: { type: Number, value: 0 }
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Jsbin: http://jsbin.com/bejahumeru/edit?html,output

Comment: @Mowzer, btw I just noticed that your example uses `<template is="dom-bind">` inside `my-view.html` - I don't think it's good practice to do that. `dom-bind` should almost always be used only from the main doc (index.html), and if and only if you require Polymer's sugar from the main doc itself.

Comment: Upvoted. But can you get your example to work "one level down" — with the `<paper-tabs>` and `<neon-animated-pages>` inside a custom element instead of the `index.html` file? That's an essential part of the setup I think might be contributing to the problem because of the `<template is="dom-bind">` issue. I upvoted your answer but I need the custom element issue addressed in order to be able to accept it.

Comment: Sure - it's exactly the same idea - I've updated the answer and jsbin.

Comment: Your exemple is bugged. If you click very speedly on different tab, the differents page are superposed. I do the same before discover this post. This bug show two elements are not compatible. Need to deepening the behavior

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with my imports.

I was using:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/neon-animated-pages/neon-animated-pages.html">
```

instead of:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animated-pages.html">
```

Comment: That explains it. FWIW your questions in SO is really pleasantly formatted.